# Sails workaround for deep populate

Tags: node.js, sails.js, populate

I'm trying to deep populate a collection.

For example

```
// UnitType.js
name: { type: 'string' }

// Unit.js
unitType: {
  model: 'unitType',
  via: '_id',
  required: true,
  index: true
}

// Product.js
unit: {
  model: 'unit',
  via: '_id',
  required: true,
  index: true
},
```

The problem is, that - as far I know from internet research deep populate like

```
Product.find().populate('unit.unitType');
```

is currently not supported in sails. To achieve the result I want I currently

- query Products with populate `unit`
- query UnitTypes with the id from `product.unit.unitType``
- `.map()` `product.unit.unitType` with the response

This is of course far from ideal. I also tried using `toJSON` in the model to "pre-populate" the `unitType` -> doesn't work since this doesn't support Promises.

There are quite a few threads on so and PR's on github on this issue, but so far I haven't found a solution to this problem. Is there any way to make this better?

Comment: If you are using async/await or generators (probably not) in your workflow, you can use my gist (compile it to js) and merge it into your model , its just a WIP though... https://gist.github.com/Zaggen/7de61775ed083d10c07e

Answer (score 6):

You could try to replace [Waterline ORM](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline) with [Offshore ORM](https://github.com/Atlantis-Software/Offshore). There is a hook for sails to do that - [sails-hook-orm-offshore](https://github.com/Atlantis-Software/sails-hook-orm-offshore).

It's quite easy to implement to your existing project, because its fork of Waterline wits some more features. Only cons i found is that [sails-hook-validation](https://github.com/lykmapipo/sails-hook-validation)
 stopped working.

**How to install**

```sh
npm install sails-hook-orm-offshore --save
```

**Configuration**

`.sailsrc`

```json
{
    "hooks": {
        "orm": false,
        "pubsub": false
    }
}
```

**Defaults**

`config/globals.js`

```
adapters: true,
models: true
```

**Usage**

Now you will be allowed to [deep populate](https://github.com/Atlantis-Software/offshore-docs/blob/master/queries/query.md#populate) in your queries. For example (from documentation):

```js
User.find()
.populate('foo.bar', { name: 'foo' }) //populate foo into user and bar into foo
.exec(function(err, users) {
    console.log(users[0].foo.bar.name) // 'foo'
});
```

### Second option

**Merge deep populate with waterline**

```
npm i Atlantis-Software/waterline#deepPopulate
```

Comment: thank you for your comment, but unfortunately it doesn't work as expected (and if messes around with the whole project, which leads to not working rest calls all over my project). I guess I'll have to stick to my current solution until sails/waterline implements deep populate

Comment: So maybe just merge deep populate with waterline yourself. Uninstall that hook from my solution and execute that: npm i Atlantis-Software/waterline#deepPopulate (that is merge request for waterline)

Comment: would be really nice, but the error (timeout) is still the same

Comment: Timeout while getting the data? Have you tried to execute model method from node cli? Maybe you are trying to get too much data at once.

Comment: my bad with the timeout, the actual error is `Error: Encountered unexpected error while building join instructions for .populate(\"unit.unitType\")`

models are defined like I wrote above -> unit definately has a unitType

Comment: Try this: Product.find().populate('unit').populate('unit.unitType');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109422/discussion-between-bonanza-and-markus).

Comment: @Bonanza Guys, It works me. But, when I write find query inside nested deep value, I get the result but it doesn't filter. User.find().
   populate('userComments.metal', {
     where: {
       metal_code: 'P'
     }}).exec(function (err, response) {
    res.json(response);
  });

Comment: Is it possible to filter the nested populate? Meaning Can I add a filter on foo level ?