# SailsJs get list of objects population relationships

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sails.js, waterline

I have a model Post:

```
// Post.js
attributes:{
    name: {type:"string"},
    users: { collection: 'user', via: 'postsReceived' },
    category: { model: 'category' },
    // Plus lots of other fields and relationships to other models for example category, topic, etc...
}
```

And I have a model Users:

```
// Users.js
attributes:{
   name: {type:"string"},
   postsReceived: { collection: 'post', via: 'users', dominant: true }
}
```

A post can be sent to many users and a user may have many posts. This if fine however when it comes to populating a list of posts that a user is attached to this becomes quite difficult. I am using the below code to get the list of posts, however this does not populate the posts relationships. For example the below will only return a id for the category of the post. What is the best way (in terms of performance) to get this to work?

```
User.findOne({id:id})
.populate('postsReceived')
.exec(function(err, user){
    if(err) return res.serverError(err);
    if (user){
        var result = user.postsReceived;
        return res.json(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you look here:
 http://stackoverflow.com/a/26452990/1931536

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this that seems to work quite nicely from:

[This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36679801/1531541)

The answer in the question above suggets using [sails-hook-orm-offshore](https://github.com/Atlantis-Software/sails-hook-orm-offshore)